# How to apply ng-class based on a DIV text - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following ng-repeat in a table;

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours">
            <td >{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>
            <td ng-class="{'full' : }" ng-click="checkSlotAvailability(hour, entry, jobLength, data)" ng-repeat="entry in data.calendar" >
                {{entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) ? 'AVAILABLE' : 'FULL'}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    .full{
        background-color: red;
     }
```

I want the table cells to display red where there's 'FULL' text on the cell. What pairs with `'full'` in `ng-class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using negation operator. You want `.full` class to be applied only if `entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)`is false ( the criteria for FULL text to appear)

```
ng-class="{'full' :!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)  }"
```